# Difference between different hex types/representations in Python

Tags: python, types, hex

Working my way through some some Python code, I'm noticing there are a number of different representations for hexadecimal values. For example, if I choose a number like so:

```
xx = '\x03\xff'
```

Then the following command (a version of which I'm using to convert little endian to big endian)

```
yy = hex(struct.unpack('>H', xx)[0])
```

will return:

```
'0x3ff'
```

However, this command

```
zz = xx.encode('hex')
```

will return:

```
'03ff'
```

Finally, printing just the value out will return this

```
'\x03\xff'
```

From the looks of it there are three different types of hex then.

1. `'\xFF'`
2. `'0xFF'`
3. `'FF'`

**What's the difference?**

***Bonus points*** if someone could suggest a better way of converting a little endian to a big endian number. The above method for `yy` won't work for numbers larger than two bytes obstinately enough and I'm working with some hex strings that are 16 bytes long  (including values that don't correspond to an ascii/integer value)

Comment: Numpy has routines to help with byte ordering, http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.byteswapping.html

Comment: Cheers. I'll have a look at that now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anything using `\x` is a string escape code, which happens to use hex notation; other escape codes include `\n` for newlines, `\'` for a literal quote, etc. A python string is a sequence of bytes and you can specify literal values outside the ASCII printable range using such characters. When Python echoes a string value back at you in the interpreter, or you print the result of a `repr()` call on a string, Python will use such escapes to represent any byte that cannot be printed as a ASCII character instead:

```
>>> chr(65)
'A'
>>> chr(11)
'\x0b'
```

The `hex()` function returns a very specific string representation, as does `.encode('hex')` with the difference being that the former includes the `0x` prefix. There are two more methods to produce such string representations; using the `'%x'` and `'%X'` string formatters, which use lowercase or uppercase letters for the representation.

```
>>> hex(11)
'0xb'
>>> '\x0b'.encode('hex')
'0b'
>>> '%x' % (11,)
'b'
>>> '%X' % (11,)
'B'
```

These are all string representations though (a series of ASCII characters), and have the same relation to the original data as `str(number)` is to integer data; you have changed the type and are further away from your goal of changing the byte ordering.

Changing a piece of binary information from little-ending to big-endian requires that you know the *size* of that piece of information. If all you have are short integers, then you need to flip every two bytes around, but if you have normal (long) integers, then you have 4 bytes per value and you need to reverse each 4 bytes.

Using the `struct` module is, I think, an excellent approach because you have to specify the value type. The following would interpret `xx` as a big-endian unsigned short int, then pack it back to a binary representation as a little-endian unsigned short int:

```
>>> import struct
>>> xx = '\x03\xff'
>>> struct.pack('<H', *struct.unpack('>H', xx))
'\xff\x03'
```

Answer (score 2):

'\xFF' represents the string containing the character with ASCII code 255.

E.g.:
`print '\x41'` gives 'A' (because this is the character with ASCII code 41)

the `xx.encode('hex')` and `hex(struct.unpack('>H', xx)[0])` just give a human readable hexadecimal representation of the ASCII codes the string xx contains.
This means that the resulting string contains a number of characters between a and f or 0 and 9.