# Python base 64 decode

Tags: python, base64

I have a base 64 encoded string and when I call `base64.b64decode` on this string I received hex values of bytes:

```
>>> base64.b64decode('ut3u4RDwyk6z3pYp7hg60rH87qptHQEt+Ffxrc50ohU/lKrD0PcGYu/mC2PZusumsIn2B7krD+EG /TRXpuaHRRQS4uaMz9Lyd8vyV8p4PeyNzytdyXn7lsF5tcILiN4e7y8OX2MNf4x6y0q2QwzFB110 5cxjQHdghOWNBqPdVFkpv14+0pkZ3ugAd9hFRMEUyIWvjHbsFA5+JZZv/9lRLbo/r0f30MnKJrTa jdVi3W787G9/B6Rfg+kxWWviLlHsOk98S/HdcU+nMY6LzSzDrNx31slQjF0wuK/0tjpmML7aBGeN JqCYyfqKLu9s8c9n4vn/TtH2zyv3aRckgjrjyLy2+/6T/jR5oXDRjHu8wHUgFpDm9VkR9Y+0zcCy 4s0ZasNCeF5GNp+4YUFqcmNp7/C0m20QAAAAlF5P7jSKksi6ESBpxL5bbA==')
'\xba\xdd\xee\xe1\x10\xf0\xcaN\xb3\xde\x96)\xee\x18:\xd2\xb1\xfc\xee\xaam\x1d\x01-\xf8W\xf1\xad\xcet\xa2\x15?\x94\xaa\xc3\xd0\xf7\x06b\xef\xe6\x0bc\xd9\xba\xcb\xa6\xb0\x89\xf6\x07\xb9+\x0f\xe1\x06\xfd4W\xa6\xe6\x87E\x14\x12\xe2\xe6\x8c\xcf\xd2\xf2w\xcb\xf2W\xcax=\xec\x8d\xcf+]\xc9y\xfb\x96\xc1y\xb5\xc2\x0b\x88\xde\x1e\xef/\x0e_c\r\x7f\x8cz\xcbJ\xb6C\x0c\xc5\x07]t\xe5\xccc@w`\x84\xe5\x8d\x06\xa3\xddTY)\xbf^>\xd2\x99\x19\xde\xe8\x00w\xd8ED\xc1\x14\xc8\x85\xaf\x8cv\xec\x14\x0e~%\x96o\xff\xd9Q-\xba?\xafG\xf7\xd0\xc9\xca&\xb4\xda\x8d\xd5b\xddn\xfc\xeco\x7f\x07\xa4_\x83\xe91Yk\xe2.Q\xec:O|K\xf1\xddqO\xa71\x8e\x8b\xcd,\xc3\xac\xdcw\xd6\xc9P\x8c]0\xb8\xaf\xf4\xb6:f0\xbe\xda\x04g\x8d&\xa0\x98\xc9\xfa\x8a.\xefl\xf1\xcfg\xe2\xf9\xffN\xd1\xf6\xcf+\xf7i\x17$\x82:\xe3\xc8\xbc\xb6\xfb\xfe\x93\xfe4y\xa1p\xd1\x8c{\xbc\xc0u \x16\x90\xe6\xf5Y\x11\xf5\x8f\xb4\xcd\xc0\xb2\xe2\xcd\x19j\xc3Bx^F6\x9f\xb8aAjrci\xef\xf0\xb4\x9bm\x10\x00\x00\x00\x94^O\xee4\x8a\x92\xc8\xba\x11 i\xc4\xbe[l'
```

I am not sure what to make out of `\xcaN` or `\x96)`? Why are there N and ) characters? If I understand correctly hex only ranges from 0-9 and a-f.
Or is it wrong to interpret them as hex values?

Comment: `\xcaN` is really `"\xca" + "N"` ,likewise `"\x96)" == "\x96"+")"` (since both N and ")" are printable ascii characters you just see them)... this looks like some sort of binary data ... where did you get the base64 encoded string? and what is the context of it

Comment: Related: [Difference between different hex types/representations in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13123877).

Comment: @JoranBeasley So that means I don't get the output as a string of bytes then when I call base64.b64decode()?

Comment: Python will show cahracters with code points above 127 in the form `\xab`, because it's completely unclear what string encoding they are in.  We can't really tell you the meaning of this string either.

Comment: @ArunavDev in python2 bytes is the same as a string ... since a character is exactly one byte wide ... (for proof `bytes("Hello Python World")`)  (anything that it can show as ascii printable characters it does ... but as mentioned anything above 127 can only be represented as its hex escape code ... if you want a character you need to use `str.decode` to tell python how that character is encoded